# Are there any security concerns with storing a JSON array as a variable in an HTML webpage?

Tags: json, security

I am coding an HTML webpage with an AJAX call where the user gets a JSON array.

Is there any reason why I should not store the JSON array in a variable to perform actions on the JSON array at a later stage? For example, when the user clicks on a button, a value is retrieved from the JSON array, and then displayed in a textbox.

I am thinking in terms of security when I ask this question.

Comment: Cross site scripting jumps to mind. If someone can manipulate the values from say something like a query string then this might be a problem if not properly encoded.

Comment: How should I implement the encoding?

Comment: @Dane: If there's an XSS vulnerability it does not matter if the data is already a variable or not, although granted it does make it easier because the variable will be automatically populated in the `window` object. However, a determined attacker could simply make the AJAX request from their XSS attack to grab the same data.

Comment: How would the attacker populate the AJAX request? I'm talking about non persistent XSS when I mention a query string, granted it also could be persistent if the object is saved.

Comment: @dan Exactly the same way that the site populates it.

Comment: @SilverlightFox I see, could you provide an example article explaining this please?